# Culture in Web API not used by FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, culture, fluentvalidation

I have a Web API, and in global.asax I set culture as follows:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
{
  var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

I have added the Fluent Validation for .NET nuget, and so in the bin folder I have /nl/FluentValidation.resources.dll.

Next, I have a validator like:

```
public class AddWeightCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<AddWeightCommand>
{
    public AddWeightCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(command => command.PatientId).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(command => command.WeightValue).InclusiveBetween(20, 200);                       
    }
}
```

And this is called from my command like:

```
new AddWeightCommandValidator().ValidateAndThrow(request);
```

The problem is that validation messages are still in English instead of Dutch.

If I debug, right before the validator is called the culture is correctly set on CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture.

Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC some messages in FluentValidation are translated and some aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the tip of Stijn I started to look on how I could use my own resources for Fluent Validation, and this is how I did it.

In global.asax, culture is set and the resource provider type for Fluent Validation is set depending on that culture:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
{            
    // Set culture
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    // Set Fluent Validation resource based on culture
    switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString())
    {
        case "nl-BE":
            ValidatorOptions.ResourceProviderType = typeof(Prim.Mgp.Infrastructure.Resources.nl_BE);
            break;
    }            
}
```

After this, Fluent Validation will look for translations in the appropriate resource file.

The resource files are in a separate project. Here, all Fluent Validation keys are defined, like inclusivebetween_error etc. Also, the various properties like WeightValue are defined there.

Finally, in the validator, WithLocalizedName is used to localize the property names:

```
RuleFor(command => command.WeightValue).InclusiveBetween(20, 200).WithLocalizedName(() => Prim.Mgp.Infrastructure.Resources.nl_BE.WeightValue);
```

Comment: It seems that this solution does not consider concurrency because `ValidatorOptions` is a static class

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/localization.html) I´d recommend supplying a custom `LanguageManager`.

In the example the translations are written in code but enumerating your resx should not be too hard. Your approach might work just as well though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
 RuleFor(rule => rule.CultureName).Must(BeValidateCultureInfo).WithMessage(errorMessage => string.Format(CultureNameInvalidMessage, errorMessage.Locale));

  private bool BeValidateCultureInfo(string locale)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(locale))
        return true;
    try
    {
        var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(locale);
        return true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```